# Wrong UITableViewCell height with UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I make custom cell with 2 multiline labels and pin this labels to all sides. When in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for **iOS >= 8** I return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. But when table view appears the cell height is bigger than should be. After I scroll down and then scroll up the cell takes the normal height. How to fix this behavior?

Code for height:

```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8) {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }

    static CCTopicTableViewCell *cell;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"topicCellIdentifier"];
    });
    cell.topic = [self.topics topicAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1;
}
```

And the result:

[image]

After scrolling:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is gone when I don't set tableView's estimatedRowHeight for iOS 8 and update preferredMaxLayoutWidth every time when sets the text for multiline labels

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue. Not sure I understand why it fixes it but I'm sure after more researching of the topic It'll come to me. Thanks again!

Comment: I kept estimatedRowHeight as it is, added preferredMaxLayoutWidth on problematic UILabel before setting attributedString and it worked. +1 for you!

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by setting "text" property of multiline labels to "nil":

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    _label.text = nil
}
```

Also table properies "estimatedRowHeight" and "rowHeight" should be set correctly:

```
_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Great! Worked perfectly (iOS9)

Answer (score 2):

`Automatic dimension` is not working well for some `UILabel` if that label is aligned with different label by **top edges** or **bottom edges**. Just make sure that you do not have such alignments.

Answer (score 2):

Set automatic dimension in viewDidLoad() method or viewWillAppear() (both code in same place)

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0;//(Maximum Height that should be assigned to your cell)
```

Visit [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) an intuitive guide for both iOS 7 and iOS 8